# How count logged user in cluster env?

Tags: session, spring-security, cluster-computing

I using Spring Security and I wonder how to count logged users in cluster in right way .
I don't want to use session persistence in DB .

Is it possible to use `SessionRegistry` object to resolve my problem ?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean is it possible using the default in-memory `SessionRegistry`, then no it isn't, since it only exists within a single VM. If you are load-balancing sessions between multiple servers then you'll need to implement a shared `SessionRegistry` which uses a persistent shared store of some kind.